# Usage of apostrophe - "it's" versus "its"

Tags: usage, apostrophe

Do you write `print its value` or `print it's value`?

It drives me crazy since I started learning advanced English *(Native French speaker here)*

My reasoning  would be `its` because `it is value` isn't quite correct but I would like to be sure once and for all please

Comment: I've amended your question because we call this an apostrophe, not a single quote (even if in most fonts it looks identical to a closing single quote - or just to a single quote in fonts where the opening and closing quotes look the same).  Also, it isn't a question of what we "say" but what we write.  ("It's" and "its" are pronounced identically at all times.)  So I also changed "say" to "write" in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: "print its value" is the sole standard orthography.  "Its" is the possessive form, while "it's" is short for "it is" or "it has".

Writing "its" as "it's" or vice versa is a common mistake among native speakers.

(I find your reasoning rather circular.  You argue that "print it's value" is incorrect on the grounds that "print it is value" is incorrect, but this presupposes that "it's" can't be used to write the possessive form.  In fact, you're correct and in standard English it can't, or shouldn't, be so used.  But whether this is logical is open for debate - the pronoun "one's" has an apostrophe, for example.)

Comment: It isn't logical; that's why even native speakers find it confusing! The possessive 'its' is not written with the usual apostrophe in order to distinguish it from the abbreviation 'it's'.